# In programming, what is a spanner or screwdriver?

Tags: python

This may sound like a dumb question, but I have searched everywhere and have come up with nothing. What does it mean to use a spanner or screwdriver when programming?

Comment: In what context did you hear this?

Comment: I guess you're programming on a steam engine?

Comment: You use the screwdriver to open a can of skeg remover or to crank a left-handed tent jack. A spanner is a lorry, or a crisp.

Comment: @roippi ??  Oh - games distribution :)

Comment: I was asking a colleague for some advice on learning how to program and his response (by email) was "When you do DIY, do you use a spanner or a screwdriver?" No response thus far so I thought I would try and find the answer myself.

Comment: What was the question that produced that response?

Comment: Your colleague may have asking about physical DIY stuff, referring to an actual scewdriver and an actual spanner, and trying to make an analogy, perhaps about using the right tool or something. Don't know without more context.

Comment: But now I really want to know what he was talking about. Can you post more of his response?

Comment: I asked what the best path to learning a language would be. I figured he would have some tips given he is the web programmer for the company I work for and since the internet is loaded with opinions on the subject. I've never met him before so it's hard to tell if he's just being an asshole or if it's actually a sincere question.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I apologize for being so vague. Thought there would be a definitive answer to my question in coming here. I am overwhelmed with the response though. Thanks for taking the time to try and answer my question.

Comment: Was that the entirety of his response? Is he given to cryptic or elliptical statements? Does he, by chance, speak like Yoda ("When DIY you do, a spanner or a screwdriver do you use?")?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a metaphor.

Comment: If I ever learn enough to have a worthwhile question I'll be sure to come here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to ask your colleague for clarification.

Comment: That was all he said other than "I will answer your question with a question" I guess that kind of like Yoda

Comment: I can't tell if that's more like Yoda or Mr. Miyagi. Either way, I'm sure there's some wisdom in there.

Comment: @user3092740. Try sending a counter-email answering his question with yet another question: e.g. "Does the DIY involve plumbing, or carpentry?". Perhaps he's actually asking for DIY advice in return for programming advice. You never know.

Comment: @ekhumoro Wow, I never thought he might be asking for advice. I've always been nervous about asking for help in fear of a harsh response so I may have assumed the worst.  I'll be sure to post his answer if I ever hear anything back.

Comment: Your colleague is saying that there are many programming tools, and he cannot answer your question in the abstract. You might want to learn, for example, PHP or you might want to learn Python -- they are both useful tools, but which one to use depends upon the problem you are trying to solve. This is his sarcastic way of saying that your original question is either too vague or too hypothetical to be answered.

Comment: @Rob I think you 'nailed it on the head'.

Comment: Sounds to me like he was saying "Sometimes in DIY you need a spanner, and sometimes you need a screwdriver. You don't just use one. There are more important skills than just being really good with a specific tool. And so it is with languages. You should learn how to program, not how to use a specific language. Sometimes you need a spanner, e.g. perl, sometimes you need a screwdriver, e.g. C#, (although some people still try and hit nails in with their bare hands, and some people try and use a hammer for everything)."

Comment: As an answer to your original question, I would recommend Project Euler (if you have some mathematical ability) and "learn programming language x the hard way" (if it exists for the language you choose). I would also recommending doing lots of programming, it is the best way to learn, and reading [this](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the icons you see in the IDE (Integrated Development Environment)? If yes, then the spanner icon usually refers to `Properties` of the item / control / file in context. It could also mean `Settings` although the most common icon for `Settings` is the Gear icon.

Comment: From an iconographic point of view, the 'spanner and screwdriver' sounds like "Settings" to me :)